# Not able to connect to mongo shell

Tags: gnome-terminal, mongodb

When running mongo command in terminal

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-11-15T14:47:49.452+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: 
Connection refused
2017-11-15T14:47:49.495+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: I am having Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Are you using a firewall?

Comment: No i am not using firewall

Comment: How did you install it, via apt?

Comment: yes i used apt to install mongodb

Comment: Mine works with that same install method! Start it `mongod` then `mongo` to connect it using another terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Remove lock file:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
   ```
2. Repair the mongodb:

   ```
   mongod –repair
   ```
3. Start the mongodb:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mongodb
   ```
4. Start the mongo client :

   ```
   mongo
   ```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312358/mongo-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017

Answer (score 0):

**check your mongod.log**

It is because of unclean shutdown.To detect an clean shutdown check mongod.lock size

--> **ls -ltr /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock**

To fix this run mongod on different port.

For ex.
mongod --port 40000

After executing the above command mongod will recover from unclean shutdown

and then type Ctrl+C to kill safely the current server running with port 40000

and then run mongod as you always do.